# How to expose webClient metrics in prometheus?

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, prometheus, spring-webclient

I want to expose the metrics of a WebClient call to a downstream system from the service, metrics like count of request, min, max time for the response is needed.

I want to know how I can write a gauge for a reactive webclient.

Here is a sample MeterBinder that I'm interested to use with webclient.

```
class Metrics : MeterBinder {
    override fun bindTo(registry: MeterRegistry) {
        Gauge.builder("metrics", Supplier { Math.random() })
                .baseUnit("status")
                .register(registry)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get the metrics of the WebClient call you can use [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) which is used as an interceptor. By default, there is one implementation of ExchangeFilterFunction i.e [MetricsWebClientFilterFunction](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/client/MetricsWebClientFilterFunction.java) which can be added as a filter with your WebClient to give metrics like Number of request count, response time and total response time.

```
  val metricsWebClientFilterFunction = MetricsWebClientFilterFunction(meterRegistry, DefaultWebClientExchangeTagsProvider(), "webClientMetrics")
  WebClient.builder()
           .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/test")
           .filter(metricsWebClientFilterFunction)
           .build()
```

This will expose all the metrics of this WebClient Call in prometheus.
Sample Prometheus Output:

```
webClientMetrics_seconds_count{clientName="localhost",method="GET",status="200",uri="/test",} 2.0
webClientMetrics_seconds_sum{clientName="localhost",method="GET",status="200",uri="/test",} 2.05474855
webClientMetrics_seconds_max{clientName="localhost",method="GET",status="200",uri="/test",} 1.048698171
```

To write custom metrics you can implement ExchangeFilterFunction and write your custom implementation for getting the metrics and add it in the WebClient Filter.

Comment: You can also autowire default WebClient.Builder which can give you metrics by default.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring Boot 3, when *MetricsWebClientFilterFunction* is not available:

```
observationRegistry = ObservationRegistry.create()
observationRegistry.observationConfig().observationHandler(DefaultMeterObservationHandler(meterRegistry))
WebClient.builder()
    .observationRegistry(observationRegistry)
    .build()
```

Sample Prometheus Output:

```
http_client_requests_seconds...
```