# How to expose outbound metrics for prometheus for the webclient requests?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, outbound, prometheus-java

Hi I am quite new to prometheus metrics. I need to expose the `http_client_requests_seconds_count` and `http_client_requests_seconds_sum` for the requests to the down stream servers.

I have enabled the prometheus in my project by

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,metrics,prometheus
```

I have added dependencies as below in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and I can see the inbound matrix in `http://localhost:8092/actuator/prometheus`. Like `http_server_requests_seconds` and others but unable to find the downstream metrics.

I am using spring web-flux reactive framework.

Comment: This question could be answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632953

Comment: Thanks Tony, I tried to implement the code and posted here. I still could not see the metrics... Could you please help identify the issue? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this answer: [stackoverflow.com/a/58632953](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632953) I tried it and found no luck.
The simple answer is just to add `AutoWired` to `WeclientBuilder` and build your `Webclient` out of it.

```
@Autowired
private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

this.webClientBuilder.baseUrl(host)
        .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
        .build()
        .post()
        .uri(uri)...
```

Configure the metrics name in `application.yml` like below:

```
management:
  metrics:
    web:
      client:
        request:
          autotime:
            enabled: true
          metric-name: Any_Prefix_http_client_requests
      server:
        request:
          autotime:
            enabled: true
          metric-name: Any_Prefix_http_server_requests
```

That's it, you will get outbound metrics in `/atuator/prometheus....`

Thanks! Happy coding

Comment: What is clientHttpConnector ?